# Where to find every-day healthy food near Heathrow Airport?

Tags: united-kingdom, health, food-and-drink

My friend is long-term traveling to Hounslow, UK, and will be working in Heathrow Airport. However, he got sick recently, and has lost a lot of weight. He is still recovering.

He was told that there is no restaurant close by their workplace, and employees would bring food from home, and he doesn't want to cook. He is thinking of quitting on his 1st day.

As a last resort effort, I am asking here for any recommendations on where he could eat (take-away is OK), with the following very specific criteria:

- Reachable only by foot or public transport
- Not spicy (e.g. Indian food is a no-go by the doctor)
- Daily food (so fast food would not be a choice)

Edit: He will be working in the [British Airways West base](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/194619617#map=15/51.4702/-0.4146), and I guess passenger terminal is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Tesco Extra supermarket at
Dukes Green Ave, Feltham TW14 0LH
which is about 1 mile walk from Hatton Cross. It has a cafe, and food counters for:

```
Meat
World Food
Halal
Asian
Polish
Fish
Free From
Afro Caribbean
```

https://www.tesco.com/store-locator/uk/?bID=2532

As well as ready-made sandwiches, salad bowls etc, big British supermarkets have lots of "ready meals" many of which just need 5-10 minutes in a microwave oven. It is likely that his break room will have a microwave he can use.